# Simple image upload in onedrive buisness

Tags: onedrive

I am exploring simple file upload API PUT /drive/root:{item-path}:/content. I am successful on uploading file with simple text. I have issue with Images. I formed the request as below
Content-Type -image/jpeg
and Request body as base64 encoded data of image

Which results 201 created as response.I could see file is created in account. Whenever i try to open the file it is blank and whenever i try to download, It says "file is corrupted, damaged or to large to open"

anyone has tried image upload in onedrive 2.0 API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be base64 encoding the image data in the request body - you should be providing the raw bytes of the image to the service as it will persist whatever you give it.

Comment: I could upload the files now. Whenever I upload the videos of .wmv extentions. GET /drive/root/children returns it as file and there is no video complex type. Which type of video should be uploaded to get the video extentions?

Comment: For performance reasons, files are uploaded directly to the store. It's only later that they're detected as photos/videos and the appropriate metadata extracted. That process is generally pretty quick, but for larger videos etc it can take time. If you wait a little, and then call again, do you see the metadata appear?